# Is there any position limitation on the insert hint for std::map?

Tags: c++, stl

I just found std::map.insert could accept an iterator as its first parameter as a search hint for the insertion process, such as `map.insert(hintIterator, insertElement);`. But is there any position requirement for the hint element? Does it need to be just before or after the insert position?   By the way, how much effect does the hint iterator position have on the insertion efficiency?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be anywhere from `begin()` to `end()`. If you pass in an iterator corresponding to the ideal insertion position you can massively improve the insertion cost does to searching for the correct location.

From the [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueSortedAssociativeContainer.html) site

> Complexity guarantees
>
> Insert with hint is logarithmic in
>   general, but it is amortized constant
>   time if t is inserted immediately
>   before p.

To understand why this is, think about the algorithm that's being applied. `std::map` has items arranged in some order, and in order to find the correct insertion point the items must be walked through until it finds a position where one item ("A") must precede the new data and the next item ("B") must follow it. Given this location in advance the search can be eliminated.

The new data has to go between these two items, and update the links between them. At the very least (for forward-iterable containers) item A must be updated to point to the new data, which subsequently points to B. If the contained is reverse-iterable, B must also be updated to point to the new data.

How should the location be specified? One must know wither A or B. As Cubbi points out, and discussed on [alt.comp.lang.learn.c-cpp](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/alt.comp.lang.learn.c-cpp/2005-03/0656.html) the 2003 standard differs on what the hint should be. The SGI documentation suggests B is the one needed, while the standard suggests A. Possibly (given that `std::map` has bidriectional iterators) it doesn't matter. I would suggest, though, that the position of the lower item (A) would be best, since you can always expect to be able to continue searching forwards.

**UPDATE:** Since educated guesses are useless until validated, here is a quick test:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef std::map<unsigned int,unsigned int> map;

    const unsigned int k=100000;
    const unsigned int reps=10;

    // Avoid edge cases by padding either end
    map srcMap;
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i!=k;++i) {
            srcMap.insert(std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
        unsigned int l=3*k;
        for(unsigned int i=2*k; i!=l;++i) {
            srcMap.insert(std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Hint is always the position of the preceding value\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i!=reps;++i)
    {
        map testMap(srcMap);
        map::iterator p=testMap.lower_bound(k-1);
        unsigned int l=2*k;
        std::clock_t start = std::clock();
        for(unsigned int i=k; i!=l;++i) {
            p=testMap.insert(p,std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
        std::clock_t end = std::clock();
        std::cout << static_cast<double>((end - start) ) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hint is always the position of the following value\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i!=reps;++i)
    {
        map testMap(srcMap);
        map::iterator p=testMap.lower_bound(2*k);
        unsigned int l=k-1;
        std::clock_t start = std::clock();
        for(unsigned int i=2*k-1; i!=l;--i) {
            p=testMap.insert(p,std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
        std::clock_t end = std::clock();
        std::cout << static_cast<double>((end - start) ) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hint is always the start of the container\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i!=reps;++i)
    {
        map testMap(srcMap);
        unsigned int l=2*k;
        std::clock_t start = std::clock();
        for(unsigned int i=k; i!=l;++i) {
            testMap.insert(testMap.begin(),std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
        std::clock_t end = std::clock();
        std::cout << static_cast<double>((end - start)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "No hint\n";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i!=reps;++i)
    {
        map testMap(srcMap);
        unsigned int l=2*k;
        std::clock_t start = std::clock();
        for(unsigned int i=k; i!=l;++i) {
            testMap.insert(std::make_pair(i,i));
        }
        std::clock_t end = std::clock();
        std::cout << static_cast<double>((end - start)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my little netbook running MinGW GCC 4.5 I got:

> Hint is always the position of the preceding value
>      94 109 109 109 109 109 110 110 110 94
>      Hint is always the position of the following value
>      109 94 109 94 110 110 109 109 110 110
>      Hint is always the start of the container
>      188 172 172 187 172 172 235 187 172 187
>      No hint
>      172 171 172 172 172 172 172 172 171 172

So I'd say hinting on either side gives about the same result, and is always better than no hint at all. Choosing a poor hint position (such as the start) is worse than no hint at all.

Comment: Is it amortized constant time if t is inserted immediately  after p?

Comment: @Thomson-tan: Yes, should be same, and possibly insertion after p is better. See updated answer.

Comment: @Thomson-tan: Looks like there's no difference - see the numbers in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [Unique Sorted Associative Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueSortedAssociativeContainer.html) concept:

> Insert with hint is logarithmic in general, but it is amortized constant time if t is inserted immediately before p.

And only this about the hint iterator:

> The argument `p` is a hint: it points to the location where the search will begin.